# Why Insert before first child not working

Tags: javascript, foreach, insert, parent-child, element

If the element has children insert a new div `"i-new-element"`. parent2 and parent3 get a new div.

child3-parent3 has children but doesn't get a new giant. Why?

How can I make it possible for children who have children to get a new div?

it should look like:

```
<div id="child3-parent3">
  <div id="i-new-element"></div>
  <div id="child3"></div>
  <div id="child4"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll("#container > *");

container.forEach(function(div) {
  {
    if (div.hasChildNodes()) {
      let parentElement = div;
      let theFirstChild = parentElement.firstChild;
      let newElement = document.createElement("div")
      newElement.id = "i-new-eleemnt"
      parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, theFirstChild)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent1"></div>
  <div id="parent2">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3-parent3">
      <div id="child3"></div>
      <div id="child4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent3">
    <div id="child5"></div>
    <div id="child6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_

Comment: `document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll("#container > *")` -> `document.querySelectorAll("#container > *")`

Comment: What makes sense then? How do I reach out to all parents, even if they are in children?

Comment: _"What makes sense then?"_ - Don't search for `#container` _in_ `#container`. I've given an "answer" (+ a CV because I don't think that this will help future readers) in my third comment. And you now also have an answer with that same solution from Garik.

Comment: Andreas Thank you for your reply. Only parents parent2 and parent3 get a giant. What can I do to give child3-parent3 a new div, because he also has his children. Parent-children-grandchildren ... and so on

Comment: Use a _"contains"_ selector (`[...*="..."]`) and get all "parent" elements (maybe @GarikHarutyunyan can add this to his answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var elements = container.querySelectorAll(":scope *");
```

instead of

```
var container = document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll("#container > *");
```

should fix your problem.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
   var elements = container.querySelectorAll(":scope *");

elements.forEach(function(div){
  {
    if (div.hasChildNodes()) {
      let parentElement = div;
      let theFirstChild = parentElement.firstChild;
      let newElement = document.createElement("div")
      newElement.id = "i-new-eleemnt"
      parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, theFirstChild)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent1"></div>
  <div id="parent2">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3-parent3">
      <div id="child3"></div>
      <div id="child4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent3">
    <div id="child5"></div>
    <div id="child6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit**: Further information about the `:scope` CSS pseudo-class can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/03/What-s-the-CSS-scope-pseudo-class-for) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the following, even it is not described well in your sample HTML:

`<div id="parent1"></div>` per instance is actually not an empty node but contains some text i.e. `<div id="parent1">some text here</div>`.

You might believe or not, but `node.hasChildNodes()` will count any text as a child node (text node, nodeType = 3), so it will always return `true` is any text is present.

To avoid that, you can filter the text nodes first or just use this workaround:

Replace this line:

```
if (div.hasChildNodes()) {
```

with that line:

```
if (div.children.length) {
```

children property is not counting text nodes.

That's all you have to do, I believe.

```js
var container = document.querySelectorAll("#container > *");

container.forEach(function(div) {
  {
    if (div.children.length) {
      let parentElement = div;
      let theFirstChild = parentElement.children[0];
      let newElement = document.createElement("div")
      newElement.id = "i-new-eleemnt";
      newElement.innerHTML = 'i-new-eleemnt'
      parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, theFirstChild);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent1">parent1</div>
  <div id="parent2">parent2
    <div id="child1">child1</div>
    <div id="child2">child2</div>
    <div id="child3-parent3">child3-parent3
      <div id="child3">child3</div>
      <div id="child4">child4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent3">parent3
    <div id="child5">child5</div>
    <div id="child6">child6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reflective, thanks, this completes Garik answer.

Comment: I don't think his answer will work if you have node like that `<div id="parent1">parent1</div>` - you can check yourself. But what's the idea of having no text there?

Comment: I looked, true, it doesn't work if text is inserted. However, my question was related to the problem of inserting div before children. Garik find solution widh scope. Your answer completes the following problem that occurs if text is inserted.